# NullPointerException Mock when use RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, spring-boot-test

I am new to using **mockito** and I have a problem. I wrote a *controller* test and it uses **restTemplate** to get data from another *api*, but when I run the *test*, the variable of this type is **null**. In result **NullPointerException.**

What could be the problem?

**Controlle:**

```java
 @GetMapping(value = "api/cstat", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> cstat() {
               ResponseEntity<DTO> response =                  // <=====NPE
                            restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, DTO.class);    

                    if (response.getBody() != null).     //<==== AND HERE NPE(on future))
                    {
                       ...
                    } else {
                        ...
                    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
   
            Dto expected = new Dto();

            String actual = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                                .get("/api/cstat").with(roleLmsRead()))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you don't have `restTemplate`, so `restTemplate` is null.

To initialise this, in the test:

- You need to declare restTemplate. E.g.

```
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

- Then you need to inject this to your `mockMvc`. E.g.

```
@Inject
private Mvc mockMvc;
```

In case of you're not writing test using the annotation style like this. You can do:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    restTemplate = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
    mockMvc = new MockMvc(restTemplate);
}
```

P/S: If `mockMvc` is the one you're gonna test, so don't name it as prefix `mock`, it's confused.